# Apache lang3 constants cannot be found

Tags: java, apache

I'm trying to use apache `commons-lang3`, using maven with version 3.1

Result for `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.SPACE`:

`SPACE cannot be resolved or is not a field`

What am I doing wrong here? Accoring to docs there should be a SPACE constant:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `commons-lang` version `3.1` or prior ? Because the `SPACE` constant was only added with version `3.2`. See the [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#SPACE).

Comment: Omg I totally overlooked the since. Yes as 3.2 is still SNAPSHOT I'm not using it yet...